# Reformat a string in java, including the extension

Tags: java, string, string-formatting

How do I format a string in java?

For eg, how to convert "photo. jpg, Warsaw, 2013-09-05 14:08:15" to "Warsaw02.jpg"?

The format is “photoname.extension, city_name, yyyy—mm—dd hh:n-m: ss" and should be converted to "city name number based on the time and place taken.extension".

Comment: Is it always that format and that output?

Comment: How do *you* make decision that result should be `Warsaw02.jpg`? What logic are you using?

Comment: The result is based on the date and time and the format is <place><number based on time and date>.<exe>

Comment: @KKasi That doesn't make sense, what's the date/time got to do with the how you determine the output?

Comment: The time and date mentioned in the first string

Comment: How is `02` related to `2013-09-05 14:08:15`?

Comment: @KKasi Your question is in danger of been closed for been unclear, we need more information about how the `02` is generated

Comment: 02 is generated on the basis of time and date, for eg:"photo. jpg, Warsaw, 2013-09-05 14:08:15" is Warsaw02.jpg and "my-Friends.png, Warsaw, 2013-09-05 14:07:13" is Warsaw01.png.

Comment: You need to set the explanation in the question. You also need to do it better. Tell that you have a list of such strings, and that you compare the dates of the pictures that are in the same city, to give them a number that orders them historically.

Answer (score 0):

Design a little class to describe each photo. At least your class should have instance fields for place name and date and time (use a `LocalDateTime` from `java.time` unless time zone is relevant). Write a constructor or method to convert your original strings into such objects. Use a regular expression for parsing the strings.

Group your objects by city name and sort each group chronologically. Decide what you want to do if there are more than 100 photos from one city, since the two-digit numbering will no longer be sufficient. Iterate through the sorted objects to format your strings. Use a NumberFormat or DecimalFormat for formatting the numbers.

You will learn more from doing the coding yourself, and I hope it will also be fun and give you satisfaction, so I am not taking that part away from you.